# Find the equation of the hyperbola?

Tags: analytic-geometry

The hyperbola being an orthogonal parabola, for which $(-1,2)$ is a focal point and $x-y+1=0$ is an asymptote.

If I have the equation for the asymptote $y=x+1$ is the center $(0,1)$?

I do not know where to proceed next.

Comment: It's better to show some work or share your thoughts on the problem so people can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The center is $(-1,0)$.

Since the hyperbola being an orthogonal parabola, we have
$$\frac{(x-p)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(y-q)^2}{b^2}=-1.$$
Since $(−1,2)$ is a focal point, we have
$$-1=p, 2=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+q.$$
Since $x−y+1=0\iff y=x+1$ is an asymptote, we have
$$1=\frac ba, 1=-\frac{bp}{a}+q$$
Now we have
$$q=0, p=-1, a=b, a^2=2.$$
Hence, the center is $(p,q)=(-1,0)$.

Comment: I think it's good to leave some spaces for OP to give his/her own try.

Comment: You are right. I'll do so.

Comment: I do not understand how you got -1=p, 2=sqr(a^2+b^2)+q? Is there a special formula for this?

Comment: and also the part 1=-bp/a + q ?

Comment: If $(x^2)/(a^2)+(y^2)/(b^2)=-1,$ then focal points are $(0,\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$ and its asymptotes are $y=\pm\frac ba x.$ Now we translates its center from $(0,0)$ to $(p,q)$, the focal points are $(p, \sqrt{a^2+b^2}+q)$, and its asymptotes are $y-q=\pm\frac ba (x-p).$

Comment: Okay so I do get it now. I get b^2=2 as a and b are equal. So the equation of the hyperbola is y^2/2 - (x+1)^2/2=1. However there are two solutions. The other one is (x-1)^2/2 - (y-2)^2/2=1 but I do not know how they get it. Does it have to do something with +/- b/a?

Comment: I understand what you think. At first, I set $(x-p)^2/a^2+(y-q)^/b^2=1$, but I faced some strange things. Sorry, but I forgot the details. Just try the case, you'll face something strange.